# Migration without any apparent advice to OP

Tags: discussion

I just noticed that a question (https://superuser.com/questions/934193/teamviewer-issue) has been migrated from security.stackexchange.com 1 hour ago.

The question was asked 17 hours ago and concerns an incident where someone unfortunately (for whatever reason) granted full access to his PC (via TeamViewer) to another person.

Although the question may be off topic for security.stackexchange.com (the migration message gives no reason), I'm surprised that before voting for migration nobody appears to have given him the minimal basic advice as to what do, something along the lines of:

> Change all of your banking and email passwords immediately from
>   another (uncompromised) machine. Even better call your bank (assuming
>   you have online internet banking or have used your credit/debit card
>   online)

Although I've now added this as a comment to the question, the OP does not have an account on SuperUser so I cannot be sure he will even see the comment.

In a situation like this surely we can do better.

The OP could possibly have had all his email accounts hijacked and his bank account(s) emptied by now.

Comment: Clicking the backlink provided in the migration brings you to the history of the InfoSec question.  Which says that the question is Off-Topic.  When the OP clicks on the question referenced in InfoSec it will take them to new SU question, regardless of him signing up for the site.

Comment: @raz I didn't know about the backlink functionality ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question did not seem to indicate a lack of awareness of the impact of this incident on his data "He probably knows my IP, all the logs, system info, registry etc., literally everything." But rather, he is asking about the technical methods to regain control of his machine, which is why it was migrated.

For these reasons, advice about addressing his possibly compromised accounts did not seem relevant.